# convert .txt to .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, txt, file-conversion

I used a previously posted code to convert my txt files to csv. However upon conversion the rows are all mixed up on my csv file. There are 3 variables which need to be in different columns but instead the code has pasted one of the variable below the first variable (see screenshots). Can someone help me fix this? Thanks
[image: screenshot of csv file]

My code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/maany/Desktop/test/")
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
input<-filelist[i]
output<-paste0(gsub("\\.txt$", "", input), ".csv")
print(paste("Processing the file:", input))
data = read.delim(input, header = TRUE)  
setwd("C:/Users/maany/Desktop/test/done")
write.table(data, file=output, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
setwd("C:/Users/maany/Desktop/test/")
}
```

My txt file:

[txt file attachment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFlk4FzPUmCPVxZodXFB3zrC8BOFuMIH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't understand how there could be 3 columns in the output file `TN_Barley_2016_6_5_TL_UC Tahoe_2.csv` since there is 2 columns in the input file `TN_Barley_2016_6_5_TL_UC Tahoe_2.txt`.

Comment: @Julien if you open the attached txt file, it has 3 columns once you ignore the top part which has the file name etc. The columns names are 'Time min', 'Temperature degree C' and 'Heat flow (Normalized) W/g'. When I convert this file to csv format, these three columns are converted into two columns with the heat flow printed in a separate row below the time value (as shown in my screenshot). Hoping that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the first 9 lines of the `.txt` file

```r
data = read.delim(input, header = TRUE, skip = 9)
```

You'll get

```
head(data)
   min   X.C    W.g
1 0.00 40.01 -0.084
2 0.00 40.01 -0.082
3 0.00 40.01 -0.081
4 0.01 40.01 -0.080
5 0.01 40.01 -0.079
6 0.01 40.01 -0.078
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked with the file in the link.

I have the original file in directory `~/Temp`.

1. The filename is put together with `file.path`;
2. the output filename uses function `file_path_sans_ext` instead of `sub/paste`, it's tested and safer;

This is part one.

```
fl <- "TN_Barley_2016_6_5_TL_UC Tahoe_2.txt"
fl <- file.path("~/Temp", fl)
output <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(fl)
output <- paste0(output, ".csv")
```

Now write convert the first lines. Read the data in with `scan`, replace the tab characters by commas and write to file with `writeLines`.

```
txt <- scan(fl, what = character(), nmax = 9, sep = "\n")
txt <- gsub("\\t", ",", txt)
writeLines(txt, con = output)
```

And finally, the tabular data. Now yes, read/write with table read/write functions, `read.delim` and `write.table`.

```
df1 <- read.delim(fl, skip = 9, check.names = FALSE)
write.table(df1, file = output, append = TRUE, sep = ",", 
            col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```